# Issue in analyzing files using sonar lint in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonarlint

I installed sonar lint (version 7.2) in STS (version - 4.13.0), installation was completely fine.
But while analyzing the files using sonar lint, I am getting 0 issues with following logs in console -

```
Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 7.2.0.42510
Started security hotspot handler on port 64120
SonarLint analysis of project master-data-service (250 files processed)...
Starting standalone SonarLint engine 7.2.0.42510...
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://602.fwk900588128/plugins/sonar-python-plugin-3.9.0.9230.jar
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://602.fwk900588128/plugins/sonar-python-plugin-3.9.0.9230.jar
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.toPath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.withEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:104)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:115)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:62)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:1)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.run(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:393)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:201)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:157)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractSonarProjectJob.run(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

Unable to load plugin bundleentry://602.fwk900588128/plugins/sonar-php-plugin-3.22.1.8626.jar
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://602.fwk900588128/plugins/sonar-php-plugin-3.22.1.8626.jar
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:208)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.toPath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.withEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:104)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:115)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:62)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:1)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.run(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:393)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:201)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:157)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractSonarProjectJob.run(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Please help here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here upgrading from 7.1 to 7.2.0.
Rolling back to 7.1 resolved the issues at moment.

Uncheck "show only latest version..." to install previous  version.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8vS3.png)

Comment: See https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-for-eclipse-7-2-0-42510-fails/57121: "A new version with a fix has been released on the Marketplace..."